# urllib2.Request does not return full html line

Tags: python, html

I am trying to download the html source code for a website using

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='http://www.nutritionvalue.org/foods_start_with_A.html'
hdr={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
request = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
text=urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(text)
```

If you look at the html code in question, you see that line 283 is super long and it contains most of the links I need for a project. However, urllib2.Request does not return that line in its entirety. What is the problem?

Comment: What is your desired output? Which links are missing?

Comment: Look at the page source from your browser. requests is getting everything the server is sending... its just that its crappy html that doesn't close its own table.

Comment: what are you looking for that is missing?

Comment: It's the line that starts with  </table></td></tr><tr><td><table class='full_width results zero'><tr class='results'><th class='results'>Food Name&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><span class='sort' onclick='changeSortMode("name", "descending")'

Comment: @Patrick, yeah... but what do you think is missing? requests gets the same thing my firefox browser gets.

Comment: @tdelaney If you look at the webpage, it lists a bunch of food items. Basically I am trying to get all the links for each item, and the way the html code is written they are all contained in that one line.

Comment: @Patrick, one page of them are... if you want everything, then you'll have to fetch all of the pages. But the question is, what do you think is missing? The page only goes to 'Amaranth', I see "Amaranth, Uncooked" on the web page and in the beautifulsoup doc. Nothing is missing.

Comment: @tdelaney For example, none of the alcoholic beverages are included.

Comment: I go to `foods_start_with_A_page_1.html` and see 10 foods starting with A - alcohol is not among them. If I select page 4, I see alcoholic beverages, buts that on `foods_start_with_A_page_4.html`. If you want them all, you'll need to keep reading `...page-1`, `...page_2`, etc... until you find it. It has nothing to do with requests. The web site isn't handing everything out in one page.

Comment: Also the page allows choosing the number of items to display (10,20,30, or 40),not sure how it would influence the html code. I am a beginner so this is all very confusing for me.

Comment: You could keep fetching pages until it fails, assuming that means the end of pages. If you put it all in a couple of loops `for letter in string.uppercase:` and `for page in itertools.count(1)` then built your url with `foods_start_with_%s_page_4.html % (letter, page)` (unitl you hit a failing page), you'd pretty much scrape the entire site.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably having errors with your buffer. What you're going to need to do if that's the case is use a loop to write out the results in the chunks you're receiving them.

```
url='http://www.nutritionvalue.org/foods_start_with_A.html'
hdr={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
qrequest = urllib2.urlopen(request)
text = ""
chunk = True
    while chunk:
        chunk = qrequest.read(1024)
        text += chunk
    qrequest.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
```

Comment: that won't help here... he's getting all the data.